# Что должно находиться в контроллере и модели простой формы в Ruby on Rails?

Tags: scaffolding, ruby-on-rails

Я создал шаблон с формой, данные из которой должны оказаться в таблице mysql.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что должно находиться в контроллере и модели, если, к примеру, структура таблицы `News`: `id`, `title`, `content`, `author`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких элементарных вещей используйте генератор:

```
rails g scaffold news title:string content:text author:reference
```

Если автором является авторизованный пользователь, или

```
rails g scaffold news title:string content:text author:string
```

Если автор - просто поле, при отправке поста.

Он создаст контроллер, модель, миграцию и все вьюхи. `author:reference` указывает на то, что `author` - ссылка на другую модель.

Если автор - просто поле, то больше ничего делать не надо. Иначе в модели новости потребуется прописать связь:

```
belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
```

Связь `belongs_to` указывает, что каждая новость связана с одним объектом, получить который можно методом `News.author`. Параметр `class_name` указывает на модель, из которой брать объект. Если модель соответствует названию связи (`Author`), то данный параметр указывать не надо, - это значение по-умолчанию.

В модели пользователя пропишите обратную связь:

```
has_many :news
```

Связь `has_many` указывает, что один пользователь связан с многими новостями, список которых можно получить методом `User.news`

И в контроллере новостей, в методе `create`, допишите строку, задающую автором новости авторизованного пользователя:

```
@news.author = <ваш объект авторизованного пользователя>
```

Один совет: для модели новостей лучше использовать название в единственном числе, имеющее форму множественного числа, например `Announcement` (`announcements`). Это позволит сделать ваш код интуитивно понятнее и красивее. Например:

```
has_many :announcements
```

Один пользователь связан со многими новостями, и их список получаем методом `User.announcements`. Название метода во множественном числе. Rails знает, что при указании множественного числа, при связи `has_many`, надо обращаться к модели в единственном числе, так что обратится к модели `Announcement`.
При этом, мы можем получить, например, последнюю новость:

```
 @announcement = Announcement.last
```

Название переменной в единственном числе, что подсказывает нам, что она хранит один объект новости, а не список объектов. Это кажется мелочью, но в при большом объёме кода сильно помогает.

Answer (score 2):

Вы неправильно подходите к решению задачи. Почитайте [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), можно сразу перейти к 5 главе.