# Как передать странице get-параметр, при обновлении?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть модель `Plan`, она содержит информацию, какой человек, на каком проекте, в какую неделю и на сколько % работает. Можно перейти и посмотреть данные по конкретному проекту, например - `/plans?project_id=17`, на этой же странице можно добавить новую запись (использую JS). Запись добавляется без проблем, но как, при добавлении, снова перейти на эту же страницу, а не на `/plans`? Как передать параметр `id` текущего проекта?

Rails 4

Comment: в смысле вы добавляете c помощью js, но не ajax ? какой в этом смысл ?

Comment: @eicto, да AJAX там, AJAX. В Рельсах он одной опцикй включается, что для формы, что для ссылки. Только функции для успешного выполнения/ошибки прописать, и всё.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас не задан маршрут, а вы просто передаёте id через get, аки в php, то подход неверный. Надо добавить маршрут в /config/routes.rb

```
get "/plans/:project_id", to: 'plans#index', as: 'plans_project'
```

В параметре `as` указывается название вашего маршрута. По этому названию вы всегда можете его вызвать.

В вашем PlansController, в методе create должна быть запись, вроде:

```
def create
    @plan = @project.plans.new(plan_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @plan.save
        format.html { redirect_to plans_project_path(@project), notice: 'Plan was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: plans_project_url(@project) }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @plan.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

И в методе new:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@plan = @project.plans.new
```

Измените `redirect_to` в `format.htm` и параметр `location` у `render` в `format.json` на `plans_project_path` и `plans_project_url`. В качестве параметра передайте им объект родительского проекта, как показано в примере выше.

И в index у вас неверно:

```
@project_id = params[:project_id]
@plan = Plan.where("project_id == ?", @project_id)
```

Надо заменить на:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) # Получаем объект проекта по id.
@plans = @project.plans # Получаем все планы связанные с данным проектом.
```

Чтобы это сработало, убедитесь, что в моделях [прописаны связи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/296604#296651). В plan.rb:

```
belongs_to :project
```

И в project.rb:

```
has_many :plans
```

Comment: Сорри, сначала подсказал, как сделать ровно наоборот)

Запись бралась из моего JournalsController, и переписана под ваше название модели.

Comment: Risco, спасибо за информацию. Есть вопрос:
Зачем нужно переходить на страницу show, ведь я делаю выборку по project_id, а не по plans_id? Мне не нужно переходить на конкретную запись модели Plans. Код в PlansController 
index  
def
  @project_id = params[:project_id]
  @plan = Plan.where("project_id == ?", @project_id)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
   end
end
Возможно это неверный подход?

Comment: @lirikk12, да, неверный. Обновил свой ответ, просвещайтесь)